# Changing the format of data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have string `A`. I want to convert into an array but I am facing an error. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import ast
import numpy as np

A = '\n[array([[[   0,   22],\n [   0,   23]]], dtype=int64)]'

# Remove unnecessary characters and fix dtype
A_cleaned = A.replace('\n', '').replace('dtype=int64', '').strip()

# Extract the content inside the outermost brackets
start_idx = A_cleaned.find('[')
end_idx = A_cleaned.rfind(']')
inner_list_str = A_cleaned[start_idx:end_idx+1]

# Replace 'array' with 'np.array'
inner_list_str = inner_list_str.replace('array', 'np.array')

# Use ast.literal_eval to safely evaluate the string as a Python literal
try:
    inner_list = ast.literal_eval(inner_list_str)
    np_array = np.array(inner_list)
    print("NumPy array:")
    print(np_array)
    print("Data type of np_array:", type(np_array))
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: Unable to convert the string to a NumPy array. {e}")
```

The current output is

```
Error: Unable to convert the string to a NumPy array. malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Call object at 0x000001709540B640>
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[[   0,   22], [   0,   23]]])]
```

Comment: print (and show us) some intermediate values.

Comment: Why do you have the `repr`  of an array to start with?  It's not designed for easy serializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Evaluate an expression node or a string containing only a Python literal or container display. **The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis.**

Which means that you cannot use `literal_eval` to parse non-native types such as `numpy.array`.

Some suggestions how you can solve this:

- use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
  (**WARNING** be careful as this might be harmful since string will be evaluated as python-code without any checks!!)
- strip off the `np.array` part as well and parse the data as a `list` with `ast.literal_eval` and then convert it to a numpy-array.

Comment: He isn't using `ast` to get an array.  Supposedly it's a list at this point in the processing,

Comment: @hpaulj I agree that a proper solution would be to check why the string contains the term "array" in the first place... however, the inability of `ast` to evaluate a directive such as `np.array(...)` was still the cause of the encountered error.

Comment: Looking more carefully at his code I see he replaces it with `np.array`.. I thought he was removing it and doing a list eval - as I've seen done on other SO.  This question often comes up when loading a csv  pandas dataframe that originally had array cell values.